# In Swift code as an array accepts the AnyObject, if we give an Interger and a Double it takes as Double value, why?

Tags: arrays, swift, arrayobject

case1:

Swift code accepts below statement as AnyObject
var array = [1, 1.0, "String"]

output for array is: [1, 1.0, "String"]

case2:

But it does not accept the below code for AnyObject and assumes it as all Doubles why
var any_object = [1, 2.0, 222222222.888888]

output for any_object is : [1.0, 2.0, 222222222.0]

Why the functionality changes from case1 to case2? 
Can any one please clarify my doubt.

Answer (score 1):

The first case has to be `AnyObject` because there are both numeric data types and a string. The second case is using the most precise form of numeric data type (in this case, `Double`) that can be inferred from the values.

If you want `AnyObject` in the second case you can specify this type on definition:

```
var any_object: [AnyObject] = [1, 2.0, 222222222.888888]
```

Comment: If I doesn't specify the datatype as AnyObject swift code it should infer I has a different datatypes

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying. Swift infers the datatype based on the items you provide at initialization if you don't specify a type. If you had an array of strings ["String1", "String2", "String3"], wouldn't you want it to infer the type as Array<String>? Swift is a strongly typed language and should encourage you to use the correct type whenever possible, that is what type inference does. It doesn't make sense for Swift to assume you will be storing a String in an array if you only initialized it with Integers. This also helps with memory allocation.

Comment: It sounds like you need to read more about type inference if you are still confused about this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference

Comment: Sorry I am not clear about the comment given by me, If I have a array consists of an Int and Double values (i.e., var array = [2, 345]) swift is assuming it as Double valued array, why this is happening?

Comment: The values of 2 and 345 have no specific type in and of themselves. You can see this if you create a Double variable and try setting it to 2 to, if 2 were only an Int, this would not work. Similarly, if you had to specify a full Double every time you wanted a Double, simply typing 345 would not suffice, you would need many more significant digits.